# Kinect depth camera got ERRORS!

Tags: ros, kinect, openni-launch, freenect-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can not open my depth camera on my Kinect when I use freenect package,and I got errors like follwing,could you help me ?

```
[ INFO] [1446804753.661709266]: Starting a 3s RGB and Depth stream flush.
[ INFO] [1446804753.661829291]: Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 0:0 with serial number 'A22596705403327A'
[ WARN] [1446804754.800842567]: Could not find any compatible depth output mode for 1. Falling back to default depth output mode 1.
[ INFO] [1446804754.815870621]: rgb_frame_id = 'camera_rgb_optical_frame'
[ INFO] [1446804754.815933870]: depth_frame_id = 'camera_depth_optical_frame'
[ WARN] [1446804754.830528673]: Camera calibration file /home/unicorn/.ros/camera_info/rgb_A22596705403327A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1446804754.830604644]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration. 
[ WARN] [1446804754.830654848]: Camera calibration file /home/unicorn/.ros/camera_info/depth_A22596705403327A.yaml not found.
[ WARN] [1446804754.830695204]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration. 
[ INFO] [1446804757.091943001]: Stopping device RGB and Depth stream flush.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220525/kinect-depth-camera-got-errors!/) by [unicornair](https://answers.ros.org/users/23386/unicornair/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2015-11-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-11-07**:
Duplicate of [fatal:can't open depth camera](http://answers.ros.org/question/220533/fatalcant-open-depth-camera/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

None of those are errors. Notice on the left how it's always  `[ INFO]` or `[ WARN]`. Are you getting output on the `/camera` topics?

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unicornair](https://answers.ros.org/users/23386/unicornair/) on 2015-11-06**:
yes,I used image_view to subscribe the /camera/rgb/image_raw topic,then I got the video stream,but when I subscribed to the /camera/depth_registered/image-_raw,I can't get any  data

**Comment by [twister](https://answers.ros.org/users/21733/twister/) on 2016-06-20**:
Actually I am facing similar problem, along with this.
[ INFO] [1466453430.535611903]:Stopping device RGB and Depth stream flush.
[ INFO] [1466453432.530449369]: Device timed out. Flushing device.
[ INFO] [1466453432.530621041]: Starting a 3s RGB and Depth stream flush.
I am not able to access RGB